# wing personal never gets beyond snap

Tags: gnome, python

I am trying to install a python IDE. I had a previous installation of spyder4.
Spyder is not in the Ubuntu software in, so I decided to try Wing Personal which is included. Wing gets installed to snap, but doesn't make it to Ubuntu itself.

I tried synaptic, but Wing Personal isn't available there. Spyder is available but it needs an additional 400 packages. I decided Wing seems to be more "modern" in the sense that Ubuntu software knows about it. I don't know why it is getting stuck at the snap stage.

I can "try" Wing by running it from snap, but that doesn't look like a serious solution.
Wing does seem to "work" better on my laptop which has python 3.9 installed, but on my desktop it complains that there is no python shell. The desktop is running python 3.10. The other difference is the desktop is running Ubuntu 22.04 whereas the laptop is still running Ubuntu 21.10.

I just tried sudo apt autoremove to see if the system would notice the Wing software in snap. Autoremove claimed that all was well. The system update tool reached the same conclusion.

I would like to get some more control over this snap problem before upgrading my laptop.
In short, I need some advice on what to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snap apps are sandboxed, and may have issues working with native python package in Ubuntu. The workaround is to replace the snap with an appropriate .deb version.

First, remove the snap version of Wing.

```
sudo snap remove wing-personal7 
sudo snap remove wing7
sudo snap remove wing-101-7
```

Next, download and install Wing's .deb file from its [official website](https://wingware.com/downloads/wing-personal).

```
wget https://wingware.com/get&prod=wing-personal&target=pub/wing-personal/8.3.0.1/wing-personal8_8.3.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./wing-personal8_8.3.0-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Does the software installer sandbox everything? In any case your solution worked. I got version 8 in place of 7. Something didn't work with your command string, so I took your advice and downloaded from their website. I managed to load the deb file with no problems. It bloody well WORKS! Thanks again..

Comment: `Something didn't work with your command string` - Which one did not work?

Comment: Snap (which the software stores uses by default) sandboxes everything for the sake of security, but it is an overkill, and many basic features do not work due to that.

Comment: Sorry to admit that I didn't investigate in any depth what exactly didn't work. It was just much simpler to take your idea of going to their web site and download the deb file, and use it.

Comment: To install via deb, use the terminal or use gnome software instead of snap store. I completely got rid of snaps to avoid these weird issues.

Comment: I deleted my long comment. Instead I will post another question which I am sure you can answer.